# sub-processes cannot stop running even if terminating pool

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I try to map_async a list of objects on a function. Since in the function, some database insertion will be executed, I have to terminate the pool to ensure database connections are killed(previously I didn't do that and I got the error 'too many connections' for MySQL). This will be iterated in a for loop like:

```
for name in names:
     data = prepare_data(name)
     p = Pool(8)
     res = p.map_async(target, data)
     res.get(timeout=300)
     p.terminate()
```

In most cases, these code works well. The databases connections in multiple sub-processes are cleaned after terminating pool. While in some cases, tasks in the last loop are still doing(log shows databases insertion is doing), and prepare_data() also begin doing. Log shows prepare_data() and target function in map_async are executing at the same time.

This seems wired, because if in the last loop, pool has been terminated, then in the current loop, when prepare_date, I shouldn't be able to see any log info in target function.

Comment: Is this due to I didn't call p.join()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the Pool to wait for its cleanup.

As you don't join the Pool, your software exits too quickly and the subprocesses get terminated abruptly.